# How can I find questions where the accepted answer has more than 800 votes in particular tag?

Tags: discussion, support, search

I want to find the questions where accepted answer has more than specified number of votes in particular tag.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't search for the questions directly, but you can get to the answer (which will obviously be on the question).

In the search bar at the top right-hand corner, enter:

```
[c++] is:answer votes:800 isaccepted:1
```

or whatever tag you want.

Examples:

- [c++ - 800+](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2b%2b%5D%20is:answer%20votes:800%20isaccepted:1&submit=search)
- [git - 800+](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D%20is:answer%20votes:800%20isaccepted:1&submit=search)
- [javascript - 800+](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20is:answer%20votes:800%20isaccepted:1&submit=search)

This will give you a list of answers. Click through them for the question.

---

Alternatively, you can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). But it's currently very out-of-date.

Comment: Searching for `c++` tag giving me your answer on one of my favorite question. :)